# Howe could one skip of some slides in presentation

Tags: beamer

I am using `beamer` class for preparing slides for my lecture. I have some questions. 
In following codes, I need to skip from  slide one to slide three; howe could I do this?

I have seen some similar questions in this site, but the answers of them did not work for my file.

```
‎\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}‎
‎\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\usetheme{metropolis}
‎‎‎\setbeamercovered{transparent}‎

‎‎‎\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb} ‎ ‎
‎\usepackage{mathtools}‎
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{serif}

‎\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{11.2}{7.2}{{Times New Roman}}}

        ‎
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=‎\large‎}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]



 ‎\begin{document}
 ‎
 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Motivations and Goals}‎
 text text text

 \end{frame}‎
 ‎
 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Budget}
 Flowers
 \end{frame}‎
 ‎
 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Target Values} \label{targets}
‎$‎F=0.52‎$‎
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You could simply use a hyperlink for that. beamer has even a special button for this: `\beamergotobutton`.

Comment: @marmot Excuse me, how could I use this?

Comment: Can you ask your unrelated question about the frame numbers as a separate question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. In this example, you can skip the second and third slides by clicking on the button in the first slide. (I would have loved to base my "answer" on your code but I could not copy it because there seem to be strange characters in it.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
\hyperlink{Slide-4}{\beamergotobutton{slide 4}} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Will be jumped over}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Will be jumped over}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 4}
\label{Slide-4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with the strange characters sounds familiar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449855/pause-a-column-of-a-table-in-beamer-class#comment1130447_449855 :)